# GIT GUI and merge using --no-ff option

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-merge, git-gui

I'm using GIT since last year and it is really really helpful...

I read a lot about the best way to use branches etc...
I actually have only one problem, I mainly use the GIT GUI

```
git-gui version 0.17.GITGUI
git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0

Tcl/Tk version 8.5.11
```

And I never found an option to do a simple merge with the `--no-ff` option

Is there any way to use this parameter? or to set it as default in GIT GUI?

reference: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't find an option in the GUI, but you could set this to be the default behavior. Open a terminal window and [set the `merge.ff` option to `false`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

```
$ git config --global merge.ff false
```

If you want to set this for only a specific repo, remove the `--global` flag.

Comment: thank you!!! you saved me here... I can finally have a better understanding of the implementations over the history... If anyone won't come up with a better solution I'll mark your answer as the accepted one! :)